# Why I haven't 0V when I put 5V in my cmos

Tags: transistors, cmos, pspice

When I Have 5v in my cmos, usually my NMOS have to be close and 0V, however there is a residual tension, I use MbreakN3 NMOS in PSPICE.
I don't think this is rd resistance because youtube tuto use it and it works.
[image]
[image]

Thank you

Comment: The drain and source of your PMOS transistor are reversed. The source of the PMOS must be connected to the higher voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a valid CMOS circuit.

The P-FET is upside down, you have drain up and source down.